# Batch script for hiding desktop icons

Tags: icons, hide, dos, desktop, batch-file

I'm trying to make a script that hides some icons on desktop. When I run it line by line in command promt it works, but when I run the *.bat file in cmd it says "attributesi was unexpected at this time."
Here is the code:

```
set address=file.ext
set attributes=attrib %address%
for /F "tokens=*" %i in ("%attributes%") do set var=%i
set var=%var: =%
if %var:~1,1%==H (attrib -H %address%)else (attrib +H %address%)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ("%attributes%") do set var=%%i
```

The for loop variables need %% instead of % when run in a batch file.  But from the command line, % works just fine.

If you need any additional help with batch files, you should check out [Rob van der Woude's pages on batch file scripting](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php).  It's a very rich resource on a language that's becoming increasingly difficult to find information on.

Speaking of which, I feel compelled to mention that Powershell scripting has largely replaced DOS batch file scripting (and for good reason).  Almost anything you can do in a DOS batch file, you can now do easier in a Powershell script.  Definitely worth checking into if you plan on doing more Windows-based scripting.

Comment: This does nothing for me

Answer (score 0):

`Hidedesktopicons.exe` wasn't doing anything for me, but link that is given actually works. http://www.actualtools.com/forum/read.php?FID=8&TID=1072